# AMPPS Yosemite Python configuration

Tags: python, macos, apache, ampps

I am have just recently acquired a new Mac (Yosemite OSX 10.10) I am reconfiguring everything and I need to work with external configs and Python on some new projects. Which bring me to two additional question:

- how to include an extra configuration with an external config file ? can I just include it to the httpd.conf of Apache from Ampps GUI? would I need to do additional settings in the Admin Panel ?
- how do I set up the mod_wsgi in Ampps, is there a specific set of actions to trigger ? will I need some specific workflow to get it to  work with my external config (bunch of virtual hosts in which some application run on Python)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, AMPPS does not work on Yosemite at all (@ v2.8)

Comment: Yip, the install page states pretty clearly that it's only for Windows, not mac: http://www.ampps.com/wiki/Install. Personally I use MAMP for the PHP stuff and then for the Python stuff I just do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296347/use-python-on-mamp